# confusion in logical operator

Tags: c, logical-operators

what will the modified values of x,y&z, this is a C language program?
And Please, Exaplain why?

```
main()
{
  int x,y,z;
  x=y=z=1;
  z=++x||++y&&++z;
  printf("x=%dy=%dz=%d",x,y,z);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only `x` get modified and that's value becomes `2`. The reason behind this is short cicuiting behavior of logical operator `||`.
Compiler interprets `z=++x||++y&&++z;` as

```
z = ++x || (++y&&++z);
```

because of the higher precedence of `&&` over `||`. 
Since `x` is `1` ,i.e, first sub-expression of `||` is true others will not be checked (and evaluated).
**Note:** You may get a warning from some compiler

```
[Warning] operation on 'z' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
```

this is because of the reason that you can't modify a variable twice between two sequence point. But in the above code `z++` never get evaluated , so its behavior is not undefined.

Comment: Well, `z` will be assigned the result of `++x`, so the values will be `x` == 2, `y` == 1, and `z` == 2.

Comment: @JohnBode; No. The whole expression returns Boolean value `1` to `z`.

Comment: Duh. I knew that. Serves me right for commenting before I've fully woken up.

Comment: @JohnBode; I happens ;)